# Como escapar HTML de uma entrada em Pyqt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

Tanto o Pyqt4 como o Pyqt5 podem interpretar entidades HTML.
Eu tenho um lugar onde o texto é exibido com formato HTML. Porém no momento de envio de um texto feito por um determinado `QLineEdit`, preciso que esse texto seja escapado, para que as tags HTML sejam convertidas para as determinadas entidades, para que o mesmo não seja interpretado.

Exemplo:

```
#Quero escapar esse valor
text = self.textChat.text()

formattedText = self._buildChatText(message)
```

Como faço para escapar um HTML de um texto de um `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 0):

Eu acabei resolvendo a situação usando o módulo `html` do Python3.

```
import html

text = html.escape(self.textChat.text())
```